# avoid displaying undefined data in list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a list that displays 12 items every set, the code is ok, its just i want to avoid display undefined data. if I click left button and it reach the last set (1,2,3,4) which is not 12, I like to adjust the list, and display 1-12 and disable also the button, same with the right button.

hope you help me.

thanks.

```js
var k = 1;
displayData(k);
function displayData(k){

var arrResults = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10, 12, 32, 41, 51, 15, 13, 11, 55, 62, 64, 75, 77, 33, 1, 5, 25, 10, 12, 32, 41, 51, 15, 13, 11, 55, 62, 64, 75, 77, 33, 62, 64, 75, 77, 33];
var len = arrResults.length;
$('.ulclass').empty();
var temp=len-(k-1)*12;
for (var i =(len-(k-1)*12) ; i >(len-12*k) ; i--) {
   $('ul').prepend('<li><p>'+ temp +'</p><p>'+ arrResults[i-1] +'</p></li>');
         temp-- ;
        }
}
$('.left').click(function(){
    k = k+1;
    displayData(k);
});

$('.right').click(function(){
  k = k-1;
  displayData(k);
});
```

```css
ul li{
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 30px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #DDD;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ulclass">
      
    </ul>
    
    <button class="left">LEFT</button>
    <br>

    <button class="right">RIGHT</button>
```

Comment: You can do an `if` check and display the results based on the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the min and max index values to always keep a full page of items on display. When the buttons are clicked and the index is adjusted, you can then test against these limits to set the buttons enabled or disabled. By tracking the index and not the page number you are able to handle an array that is not a multiple of12 and still keep 12 on the screen.

```js
var currentIndex = 0,
    resultsPerPage = 12,
arrResults = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10, 12, 32, 41, 51, 15, 13, 11, 55, 62, 64, 75, 77, 33, 1, 5, 25, 10, 12, 32, 41, 51, 15, 13, 11, 55, 62, 64, 75, 77, 33, 62, 64, 75, 77, 33];

enableButtons();
displayData();

function displayData() {
  console.log( currentIndex );

  $('.ulclass').empty();

  for (var n = currentIndex; n <= currentIndex + resultsPerPage; n++ ) {
    $('ul').append('<li><p>' + n + '</p><p>' + arrResults[n] + '</p></li>');
  }

}

function enableButtons() {
  
$('.left').prop( 'disabled', 0 >= currentIndex );
$('.right').prop( 'disabled', arrResults.length - resultsPerPage - 1 <= currentIndex );
}

$('.left').click(function() {
  currentIndex = Math.max(currentIndex - resultsPerPage, 0);
  enableButtons();
  displayData();
});

$('.right').click(function() {
  currentIndex = Math.min(currentIndex + resultsPerPage, arrResults.length - resultsPerPage - 1);
  enableButtons();
  displayData();
});
```

```css
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 30px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #DDD;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ulclass">

</ul>

<button class="left">LEFT</button>
<br>

<button class="right">RIGHT</button>
```

Comment: hi sir, how can I start on the last item? `var currentIndex = arrResults.length,` doing this doesnt work.

Comment: Try arrResults.length - resultsPerPage - 1

Comment: HI sir I add a new button which displays the results from the last item. `currentIndex = Math.max(currentIndex + resultsPerPage, arrChongqingTableGameResults.length - resultsPerPage - 1);` this is the code, my problem is the button can't be disabled. sorry for extra questions..

Comment: Might be best as a new question.  I think you need min here, not max

Comment: I used min, but the functionality is same with the right button

Comment: ill make one sir